# Javascript submit won't work on server?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, form-submit

I have the oddest bug. I have a simple html form. You can see it here:
http://www.learndoearn.org/almost_real_products/food_services.html

This form is just for demonstration purposes only. It doesn't really submit to anywhere. All I want it to do is validate a few fields and if those fields are filled in, redirect the user to a thank you page. This works fine if you physically click on the html file to open it, HOWEVER...if you try to access this html page via the domain name (as seen in the link above), clicking the submit button (once all necessary fields are filled in) doesn't work. It simply doesn't do anything.

The redirection to the thank you page occurs in this file:
http://www.learndoearn.org/almost_real_products/js/forms.js (it's about halfway down the js file where it says window.location = "http://www.learndoearn.org/almost_real_products/thanks.html";

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You gotta include the specific code that is causing the problem in your question.

Comment: we are not your code tester. track the bug and let us know.

Comment: Did you try adding an alert inside the 'success' callback? Is it being called ?

Answer (score 0):

The link you have provided to the ajax call "bin/MailHandler.php" is returning a 405 error. Due to this the success function is not being run and the redirect does not take place.

Modify your php file to return success irrespective of the input if its a dummy and it should all work fine.